# Button not working in Processing 4 beta 1

Tags: processing

I just cant have my code work. It makes the button, but it does not work. So can you help me with that?

It makes the text normally and button is showing up too. But it does not work, I tried it with different functions too like `background(10)` etc.

```java
Button login1;
boolean clicked = false;

void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  loginPage();
}

void draw() {
  if (login1.isClicked()) {
    print("AAAA");
  }
  login1.update();
  login1.render();
}

void loginPage() {
  background(27, 50, 131);
  textSize(70);
  fill(255);
  text("System Statku Organizacji 587 'Aurora'", 600, 150);
  login1 = new Button(100,50,400,200,"Zaloguj sie",64, 136, 253,255,255,255);
}

class Button {
 boolean Pressed = false;
 boolean Clicked = false;
 PVector Pos = new PVector(0,0);
 float Width;
 float Height;
 color Colour;
 color textColour;
 String Text;
 
Button(int x, int y, float w, float h, String t, int r, int g, int b, int tr, int tg, int tb) {
 Pos.x = x;
 Pos.y = y;
 Width = w;
 Height = h;
 Text = t;
 Colour = color(r,g,b);
 textColour = color(tr,tg,tb);
}
 
void update() {
  if (mousePressed == true && mouseButton == LEFT && Pressed == false) {
    Pressed = true;
    if (mouseX >= Pos.x && mouseX <= Pos.x+Width && mouseY >= Pos.y && mouseY <= Pos.y+Height) {
    
    }
  } else {  
    Clicked = false;
    Pressed = false;
  }
}
 
 void render() {
   noStroke();
   fill(Colour);
   rect(Pos.x,Pos.y,Width,Height);
   
   fill(textColour);
   textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
   text(Text,Pos.x+(Width/2),Pos.y+(Height/2));
 }
 
 
 boolean isClicked() {
  return(Clicked);
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your code (below Button class). I'm not sure that you really need the Pressed and Clicked booleans.

```
void mousePressed(){
 if((mouseX >= login1.Pos.x) && (mouseX <= login1.Pos.x + login1.Width) && (mouseY >= login1.Pos.y) && (mouseY <= login1.Pos.y + login1.Height)){
  println("You hit the login button.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it inside an button class?

Comment: The post by v.k. might do what you want: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/mouse-click-on-object.html

Comment: Try moving if (mouseX >= Pos.x ...) down to render.